# very vs fairly vs pretty vs somehow vs quite vs extremely vs really vs enough

Tags: difference, word-difference

I would like to know the difference between the following intensifiers: *very, fairly, pretty, somewhat, quite, extremely, really, enough*.
I would like to know their difference based on how strong or intense they are. How much they make the meaning of that adjective or adverb more intense, more powerful, etc.

I have the following list of sentences.

1. This black laptop is **VERY** good.
2. This red laptop is **EXTREMELY** good.
3. This blue laptop is **REALLY** good.
4. This yellow laptop is **FAIRLY** good.
5. This green laptop is **SOMEWHAT** good.
6. This while laptop is **QUITE** good.
7. This pink laptop is **PRETTY** good.
8. This orange laptop is good **ENOUGH**.
9. This purple laptop is good.

Since there is not a numeric value for each intensifier, I would like to get some help to order/arrange that list of sentences so I can see that way the level of intensity of each intensifier. I would like to order them *from the strongest to the weakest*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd order it like this:

- This red laptop is EXTREMELY good.
- This blue laptop is REALLY good.
- This black laptop is VERY good.
- This while laptop is QUITE good.
- This purple laptop is good.
- This pink laptop is PRETTY good.
- This orange laptop is good ENOUGH.
- This yellow laptop is FAIRLY good.
- This green laptop is SOMEWHAT good.

This is by no means an absolute ranking though - in some situations the order could be different. Especially with "good ENOUGH", the meaning could change depending on the context.